# Pass the monthly value of an SSRS report chart into another report with date from and date to parameters

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a yearly chart that it broken down into the 12 months Jan - Dec. The report contains various parameters including a yearly dropdown that changes the chart and report.
This all works fine within the first report.

The problem is that I have set up an action on the chart to go to a second report with a monthly breakdown, so my question is how can I pass the monthly value from the first report to the second?

The monthly report has an additional date from and date to parameter, so for the month of January it would need the values: Date From: 01/01/2010 and Date To: 31/01/2010 for example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add parameters to your report action?

Comment: What does your dataset look like?

Comment: Yes i have added the parameters to the report and created monthly and yearly dropdown lists within the report.

Comment: The dataset creates totals for the months and years then splits them into 4 areas 1 for each product, which also has a dropdown parameter. The logic works within the report itself, but i wanted the date from and date to inherit the monthly values based on the month selected. Is this at all possible or maybe i'm trying to do to much in one report? Thanks for the quick replies.

Comment: So your Chart/Dataset has integer-based year and month columns?

Comment: The year shows as an int 2010,2011, etc. The month shows as Jan - Dec, but has the value of 1 - 12. I have tried both ways of converting the int to a varchar in sql and using the actual value in the report, also the other more normal way of using the int value in the report as 1- 12 and adding the name as Jan - Dec. Both won't pass through to the secondary report.

Comment: I have got the month and year to pass through correctly, if I remove the date from and date to parameters. I think this could just be another limitation of SSRS. The only way I can see possible is adding an expression to pick up the month and year of the other parameters, then add 01 or 31 to the day? Any other ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have the year and month integer values, you can construct the start and end dates to pass to your other report using expressions.

The start of the month will be:

```
=DateSerial(Fields!Year.Value, Fields!Month.Value, 1)
```

Where `Year` and `Month` are the integer values from the Chart/Dataset.

The end date is a bit more complicated; since the day part can be 30/31, etc, but we can just add one month to the above expression to get the first of the next month, then go back a day:

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day
    , -1
    , DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, 1, DateSerial(Fields!Year.Value, Fields!Month.Value, 1)))
```

This way your drillthrough report can get its date based parameters and you don't need any changes to your dataset/parent report.